# How to keep a grid row highlighted in Janus Grid (C#)?

Tags: c#, grid, row, janus

How to keep a grid row highlighted in Janus Grid even if the user focus on another control?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GridEX1.SetFocus
GridEX1.Row = 2
GridEX1.Col = 3
GridEX1.EditMode = jgexEditModeOn
GridEX1.SelStart = 0
GridEX1.SelLength = 1000
```

Comment: why .Row = 2 or .Col = 3? is just an example?

Comment: However I haven't any of those properties instead of edit mode

Comment: Yes, It was an example

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.HideSelection=HideSelection.Highlight;
```